# Undeploy a build while migrating from one server to another server

Tags: symfony, deployment, ant, web-config

task : i want to undeploy a project as i am going to move it from one server to another.

my deployment script :

```
    <target name="deploy" depends="backup">
    <dirname file="${ant.file}" property="project.dir"/>
    <echo>Stop Apache</echo>
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop" />

    <echo>Clean deployment space</echo>
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S rm -r *"/>

    <echo>Install new app</echo>
    <scp file="${project.dir}/${project.name}.tgz" todir="${build.login}:${vhost.dir}"  password="${password}"></scp>       
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S tar xvzf ${project.name}.tgz" />
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="echo ${password} | sudo -S cp ${vhost.dir}/${project.conf}-test.conf ${vhost.conf.dir}" />
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S chown -R wwwrun:sdt *" />
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S chmod -R ug+rwx *" />

    <!--  added for Symfony 2 -->
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S rm -r app/cache/*" failonerror="false" />
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; php app/console assets:install web" failonerror="false" />
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; php app/console assetic:dump" failonerror="false" />

    <echo>Cleanup installation</echo>
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S rm ${project.name}.tgz ${project.conf}-test.conf" />

    <echo>Start Apache</echo>
    <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start" />
</target>
```

please tell me if i wish to undeploy what should i write in the script.i have symfony2 based project and build tool is Ant.

Thanks !!
    will this code as a stand alone work?

```
<property name="project.conf" value="ecweb" />
<set-property name="vhost.dir" if-property-isset="vhost.dir_ext" />

 <target name="undeploy">
 <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 stop-graceful" />
 <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd  ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S rm -r *"/>
 <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command=" cd /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/ sudo -S rm -r ${project.conf}-${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.conf"/>
 <sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start" />

 </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the following logic in your deploy script effectively undeploy your application?

```
<echo>Clean deployment space</echo>
<sshexec host="${host.name}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="cd ${vhost.dir}; echo ${password} | sudo -S rm -r *"/>
```

This isn't really an ANT question, since your running remote shell scripts.

Comment: yes it does but i want a seperate file which i can run whenever i want to undeploy a build as the above code is in my build script which clean the space and reinstall app again.

Comment: i added few lines which i think should work as a separate script will it work?